# Symfony ManyToMany unidirectional cascade persist not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, persist

With symfony 3.3 I have the entity user which as billingAddresses with ManyToMany unidirectional relation:

Entity\User

```
class User extends EntitySuperclass implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable 
{
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_BillingAddress",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="billing_address_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = 1,
     *      minMessage = "user.billing_addresses.min",
     * )
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $billingAddresses;

/**
     * Add billingAddress
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addBillingAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        $this->billingAddresses[] = $billingAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove billingAddress
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     */
    public function removeBillingAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        $this->billingAddresses->removeElement($billingAddress);
    }

    /**
     * Get billingAddresses
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getBillingAddresses()
    {
        return $this->billingAddresses;
    }
}
```

Although I added `cascade={"persist"}`, the "billingAddresses" are not persisted/saved when I persist the entity user. I also tried with bidirectional relation, but address is still not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following explicitly

```
$user->addBillingAddress($address);
```

Check if you are doing above before calling persist and flush

```
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

You have to establish the association between the entities manually. It's describe here in documentation

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#working-with-associations

Thanks!

Comment: This is an unidirectional relation, so I don't have a method "addUser()". In the doctrine doc this unidirectional relation is also mentioned. As written above, I also tried with bidirectional relation, but still has same issue. Why do I have to persist each "address" individually. Shouldn't this be done by `cascade={"persist"}`?

Comment: In case of uni directional, you can just do 
$user->addBillingAddress($address); &
$em->persist($user);

Let me know if this works, I have edited the answer as well

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work when I only persist the user, I also have to persist the address. And this I don't understand, because "user" has `cascade={"persist"}` set.

Comment: That's confusing, when you tried bidirectional, did you add `inversedBy` on User Side, so it becomes the owing Entity and `mappedBy` on address side? Does cascade persist work then?
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association

Comment: Now, also does not work, only when I persist address individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add constructor to User class

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->billingAddresses = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Comment: This I still have.